# How can I apply a style to a bullet list in Word without loosing the sub-list indentures

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document that has various bulleted lists and numbered lists some of which have sub-lists (list level 2 and 3) which are indented.

I now want to apply a new custom style to the lists which changes the font etc., but if i apply a new style the existing lists lose all their indents and sub-lists. Every item in the list goes back to list level 1. Is there a way to avoid this and keep the sub-list indents?

Comment: Have you defined a multilevel list for what you're trying to do? If not, that's what your problem is. The following tutorial will walk you through it (https://www.google.com/search?q=creating+list+outline+in+word+using+styles&oq=creating+list+outline+in+word+using+styles&aqs=chrome..69i57.17854j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=1)